# Obtain metadata associated with matched content in Solr/Lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, indexing, metadata

I've a large set of text documents which I will index with Solr, in a format where each line of text has associated metadata.  For example:

```
#metadata1
A line of text.
#metadata2
Another long, broken line of
#metadata3
text that should be searchable.
```

I'd like to index this such that the content is searchable, including phrase matches spanning multiple lines, but not the metadata.  However, I can't discard the metadata: I would like to have any matches still have the associated metadata.

E.g. A query for "line of text" would return 2 matches, one being the first line (and its associated metadata "metadata1") and the other being the second and third lines (with the associated "metadata1" and "metadata2" respectively).

Can anyone describe how this might be done, or reference a tutorial that would get me started?

Comment: what do you mean by 'a match has the associated metadata'? you want to query over metadata or not?

Comment: Metadata should not be searchable, but if the search matches a particular line, then it should be trivial to obtain the metadata that was associated with that line.  In the example, each line has a single line of metadata above it.

Answer (score 2):

Since Solr uses Lucene under the cover, you should start with the Lucene document model:

- index is a collection of documents
- A document is a sequence of fields.
- A field is a named sequence of terms.
- A term is a string.

Searching goes over one or more fields and returns documents as results. Therefore, if you want to have span queries over multiple lines, you will have to put them into one document, but then the "line of text" query will match only one document.

**UPDATE**: seems like it's possible to search across multiple fileds using [FieldMaskingSpanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/FieldMaskingSpanQuery.html).

If you don't want to search over metadata lines that's doable (you simply won't index them). Also to include metadata into results (I guess you want to store this while indexing and retrieve at search time).

Comment: Yes - right now I've split each line into a separate document, but obviously this means the spanning doesn't work.  Are you suggesting that one cannot return multiple (ranked) matches from within the same document?

Comment: Also, how would you propose to achieve the latter?  In the "every line is a document" model, I have the metadata in another field. But that wouldn't work if the lines are concatenated and placed into a field in a single document.

Comment: correct, you cant search and get one document reported more than once (multiple matches coming from within one document). Lucene will gather all the evidence for one document and combine them into a single score. You don't get many "matches", each for one piece of evidence, it just doesn't work like that.

Comment: Ok - so in summary, it is not possible to do what I'm asking in the example above?  That seems like an extremely odd limitation.

Comment: now if you put all lines into one document, i guess you would have to keep metadata using Lucene payloads. But they are per term, not per line as you need them, so it's not so strait-forward.

Comment: hm, it might be possible to do span queries across fields:  FieldMaskingSpanQuery

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6768/discussion-between-milan-and-chris-leishman)

Answer (score 1):

Configure your fieldType with a [PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) that detects and removes the metadata at index-time, and make the field stored so that the metadata is returned on a match.